# Pattern matching techniques in SQL to correctly match a string to a keyword but not getting the right results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, sql-like

I have a table (dbo.Library) where I have build a library of keywords that are associated with different titles and persona in a company. See below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Library 
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
 Persona VARCHAR(20), 
 Keyword VARCHAR(100)
 )
INSERT INTO dbo.Library 
(Persona, 
 Keyword) 
 SELECT 'CMO', 'Digital Marketing'
 UNION SELECT 'CMO', 'Marketing Operation'
```

Let's say I have another table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TargetTable
 (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  Title VARCHAR(20), 
  Persona VARCHAR(100)
  )
  INSERT INTO dbo.TargetTable
  (Title)
  SELECT 'Director of Digital transformation in Marketing'
  UNION SELECT 'Digital Marketing Analyst'
  UNION SELECT 'Marketing and Sales Operation'
```

Now I want to JOIN the `dbo.library` to the `dbo.TargetTable` on title using pattern matching to update the Persona column accordingly:

```
UPDATE A
SET Persona  = B.Persona
FROM dbo.TargetTable A 
INNER JOIN dbo.Library B 
ON title LIKE '%' + [Keyword] + '%'
```

This matches on every letter in the keyword hence I get titles that have nothing to the keyword matched to a persona. While what I actually want is:

```
UPDATE A
SET Persona = B.Persona
FROM dbo.TargetTable A
INNER JOIN dbo.Library B
ON Title LIKE '%' + 'Digital' + '%' + 'Marketing' + '%'
```

Do you know how can I solve this? Is there even a way to do exact matching of the keyword string while using [ ]?

Comment: And what if multiple keywords match a single title?

Comment: In the use case, as long as all those keywords were mapped to the same Persona, it is fine. It will be random keyword, in this case, that will win the attribution of the Persona. I assume in the use case where you didn't want to leave the attribution to randomness, you can assign record priority and build a conditional logic that would attribute the Persona in the waterfall fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply replacing embedded spaces in the keyword with wildcard character `'%'`?

```
UPDATE A
SET Persona  = B.Persona
FROM dbo.TargetTable A 
INNER JOIN dbo.Library B ON title LIKE '%' + REPLACE([Keyword], ' ', '%') + '%'
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. This made great sense in my program. Funny how It didn't even occur to me.